# Cannot convert a varchar value of 100 into number under a grade column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column entitled "Grade" and defined as VARCHAR2(3); however when I have a grade value of '100' the system under Oracle SQL cannot read this value as integer and I am not able to set up the below case condition:

```sql
WHEN CAST(GRADE as varchar(3)) between '93' and '100' then 4.3
```

##### Update:

I am getting a `0` score for the `100` value instead of `4.3`

```sql
Select CRSE_NUMB,
       Grade,
       CASE 
       WHEN CAST(GRADE as varchar(3)) between '93' and '100' then 4.3 
       WHEN Grade < '60' then 0.0
       WHEN Grade = '60' then 1.0
       WHEN Grade between '61' and '62' then 1.3
       WHEN Grade between '79' and '82' then 3.3
       WHEN Grade between '83' and '86' then 3.7
       WHEN Grade between '87' and '92' then 4.0
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION error) between '93' and '100' then 4.3 
       else null
       end as Score
from   SWBGRDE
group by CRSE_NUMB, Grade
```

Comment: Skip the varchar format, cast as number. `'9' > '10'`, when you compare strings. `9 < 10`, when you compare numbers.

Comment: CAST(Grade as number) is not working in Oracle SQL neither CAST(Grade as integer)

Comment: Try TO_NUMBER() instead of cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TO_NUMBER()`:

```
WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade) BETWEEN 93 AND 100 THEN 4.3
```

If you have non-numeric data in your `grade` column, and are on Oracle 12 or later, you can use:

```
WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) BETWEEN 93 AND 100 THEN 4.3
```

If you compare using strings then the comparison is done on substrings of successively increasing lengths so it will compare if the first character of `GRADE` is between a minimum of `'9'` and a maximum of `'1'` which will never be true.

---

For example, from Oracle 12 you can use:

```sql
SELECT grade,
       CASE
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) < 93 THEN 1
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) BETWEEN 93 AND 100 THEN 4.3
       END AS score
FROM   table_name
```

Or, in earlier versions, you can look for a non-numeric character:

```sql
SELECT grade,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(grade, '\D') THEN NULL
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade) < 93 THEN 1
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade) BETWEEN 93 AND 100 THEN 4.3
       END AS score
FROM   table_name
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (grade VARCHAR2(3));

INSERT INTO table_name (grade)
SELECT TO_CHAR(90 + LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | GRADE | SCORE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 91 | 1 |
> | 92 | 1 |
> | 93 | 4.3 |
> | 94 | 4.3 |
> | 95 | 4.3 |
> | 96 | 4.3 |
> | 97 | 4.3 |
> | 98 | 4.3 |
> | 99 | 4.3 |
> | 100 | 4.3 |
> | AAA | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d4fd007fdb2d981c95ff2d8f2f37e486)*

---

Regarding your update:

Do not compare numbers as strings - compare them as numbers and use `TO_NUMBER` everywhere:

```sql
Select CRSE_NUMB,
       Grade,
       CASE 
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) < 60 then 0.0
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) = 60 then 1.0
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= 62 then 1.3
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= 82 then 3.3
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= 86 then 3.7
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= 92 then 4.0
       WHEN TO_NUMBER(Grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= 100 then 4.3 
       else null
       end as Score
from   SWBGRDE
group by CRSE_NUMB, Grade
```

If appropriate, you can just specify the top end of the range and let the `CASE` expression short-circuit to the first match.

Comment: TO_NUMBER(grade) is not working in Oracle SQL; there must be a different function or different way to change that varchar field. However WHEN GRADE between '87' and '92' then 4.0 --> is working fine

Comment: @jean Saying "is not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us **WHY** it is not working for you. The db<>fiddle linked in my answer shows that it does work so if it does not work for you then there must be something different in your setup and unless you identify what that is and communicate it to us then it will be difficult for us to help. So, help us to help you and give us all the information by telling us what is happening: do you get an error message? do you have non-numeric grades in your table? do you just get no rows?

Comment: `WHEN grade BETWEEN '87' and '92'` will work as you can compare it as a string and look if the substrings up to the first character is between `8` and `9` and then if the substring up to the second character is between `87` and `92`. Try putting a value in of `870` and you will find that it also matches as `'87' < '870' < '92'` is true when comparing strings.

Comment: when I do: Select To_Number(Grade) --> I get no rows with the following error ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @jean, if you are on Oracle 12 or later then use `TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)`.

Comment: it works now for all records except for the 100 value, the system is returning a score value of 0 value instead of 4.3 for the '100'  --> using the below SQL -- WHEN TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) BETWEEN 93 AND 100 THEN 4.3
       END AS score

Comment: @jean It works in the example in the answer; you have **NEVER** shared your complete query (or even just the complete `CASE` expression) so I cannot comment on why it is outputting `0` and from all the code you have shared there are no options that would output `0`. If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71158126/edit) your answer and share your code then maybe we can help.

Comment: Please check my code edited and inserted again at the top of this message

Comment: Thanks it works now and finally

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quote around 93 and 100:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(100 as varchar(3)) between 93 and 100 then 4.3 END FROM DUAL
```

But since you are using number I am not sure why you are casting it to varchar. Any particular reason?

Comment: I am sorry but let's take it step by step ; the cast(grade) function as it , is not working neither To_number(grade)

Comment: my "grade" column is defined as varchar2(3)

Comment: _"my "grade" column is defined as varchar2(3)"_   That, in itself, is a serious design flaw.  If a 'grade' is a numeric value, why are you not defining its column as a numeric data type?  As it is, oracle will quite happily accept 'DOH' as a valid value for grade.  With proper data design, your problem simply ceases to exist.